# Deploy an instance of my application for every customer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualization, dropwizard

Ok, so I would like to build my application in a way that allows for each organization to get their own instance.

My way of thinking here, is that I could do something with AWS or digital ocean or whatever to deploy my java (dropwizard) application every time a new client registers their company with us.

This would be virtualized, I would be hoping, so I would have those instances running on various virtual servers.

Basically, when a company registers... I would like to spin up an instance of the core API, and an instance of the DB server (or the two could be one instance here, I guess)

Is this a thing? I would google it, but I am not fully sure what to be looking for!

I know this is not a dropwizard question - but I tagged it this way because it is a dropwizard application I am building - and I figure people in that community may have had similar concerns! Please feel free to edit!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to automate the process of spinning up an environment using something like CloudFormation, Ansible, Terraform, Chef, Puppet, etc. There are a lot of tools in this space. These tools are called Infrastructure as Code (IaC). Once you have it automated, setting up a new environment for a new customer would be a simple task of kicking off the appropriate script.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info - furthermore, do you know if there is a way to do it so it isn't quite an instance per customer, but more like it would spin up extra instances of the DB and the Server only if traffic is high? and spinning them down when traffic is low? and keeping the data synchronized?

Comment: You would use AutoScaling Groups and Elastic Load Balancers to handle spinning up web servers as needed, and shutting them down when not needed. If you want to keep environments isolated between customers you might also look into using Docker containers and the ECS service.

Databases are much more difficult to scale on demand, and the solution would depend on the exact database engine you are using. Look into using AWS Aurora as your database if possible.

Comment: Hey - paste one of these comments in as the answer below so I can mark this as the correct answer! :) Thanks!